# Styling html table's td/tr display elements in asp.mvc 3 view

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm doing this for a view from an ASP.NET MVC 3 project. I am creating table in run time because the rows, columns and the data associated with them is recorded in a database and it varies for the different tables. In the picture below you can get the basic idea of what I need to change :

[image]

The border lines that continues after the end of the table are the borders of a `<div>` tag with the same height and width as those defined for the table.

However there are several problems that I want to solve :

- The table's width gets larger than it's supposed
- Some of the elements takes two rows even if there is enough space (the first row where `alabala` is above `yes` and the next `<td>` blabla is on the same line as the textbox which is actually how I want it to be.
- Maybe this is something that sums up the things I pointed above - I want to table to keep it's size, no matter how many elements there are per row, I want the text before the textbox to appear on the same line as the textbox itself.

I have pretty poor experience in both HTML and CSS so don't know what is possible and what not, so if it's not possible to achieve exactly the output I want feel free to suggest an acceptable solution for nice table view.

P.S

This is how I actually create a `<td>..</td>` :

```
sb.Append("<td>" + innerArray[a][0].QuestionText +
          "<input type='textbox' style='border: 1px solid red' value=" +
          innerArray[a][0].FieldValue + "></td>");
```

Where : `System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();`

Comment: Why would you concat the `string`s first via the `+` operator and then pass it the the `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Well, dunno, you are right, gonna change it, but anyways it still works.

Comment: To start with; you should probably have two td elements for each innerArray value... one for the question and one for the input box

Comment: @daveL It's made like that with reason, but if you can provide a working solution when both values are in separate `<td>`'s I'll try to change my business logic.